# Make Django pass int value request param as int rather than unicode

Tags: django, unicode

I remember coming across such a question some time ago, but couldn't find a link n the internet, so asking this question possibly for the second time. It is very iriitating that Django transforms int value into unicode having to transform the value to integer on every occasion. Is there any native syntax to stop Django doing this ?

```
url(r'some_url/(?P<some_param>\d+)/$', some_view, name = 'some_url')

def some_view(request, some_param):
        a = int(some_param) # Having to write this surplus int is very very irritating
```

JS

```
$.get('/some_url/6545/', function(response){...
```

Comment: Is some_param is a model id ?

Comment: [Captured arguments are always strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#captured-arguments-are-always-strings)

Comment: Django doesn't transform anything -- and that's exactly why you receive a string. The input (the url path) is a string, and nowhere along the line does it get converted to an integer by Django. There's no option to have Django automagically convert parameters to whatever data type you have in mind -- that's your job.

Comment: Ufff...Ok. Thanks

Comment: Note that if you're just using this to get a model instance by ID, Django specifically allows you to do it without converting to int.

Comment: Daniel, as always, your comments are exceptional